# How do you render a view (for HTML email purposes) in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework2, service-locator

I've read several stack overflow posts on the subject, and they mention that in the controller you can use `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('HttpRenderer')` or something similar.

However, I am not able to get the `HttpRenderer` service, as per the exception thrown belw. What am I doing wrong?

```
======================================================================
   The application has thrown an exception!
======================================================================
 Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException
 Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for HttpRenderer
----------------------------------------------------------------------
/var/opt/projects/MYAPP/web/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:529
#0 /var/opt/projects/MYAPP/web/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/CronController.php(53): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('HttpRenderer')
#1 /var/opt/projects/MYAPP/web/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(83): Application\Controller\CronController->mailAction()
#2 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#3 /var/opt/projects/MYAPP/web/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#4 /var/opt/projects/MYAPP/web/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#5 /var/opt/projects/MYAPP/web/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php(117): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#6 /var/opt/projects/MYAPP/web/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/DispatchListener.php(114): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Console\Request), Object(Zend\Console\Response))
#7 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#8 /var/opt/projects/MYAPP/web/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 /var/opt/projects/MYAPP/web/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#10 /var/opt/projects/MYAPP/web/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php(313): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#11 /var/opt/projects/MYAPP/web/public/index.php(30): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#12 {main}
======================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed the following:

```
$viewManager = $this->serviceLocator->get('ViewManager');
```

I could then call `$viewManager->getViewRenderer()->render($viewModel)`.